# pip not getting forked repo in download

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setup.py, requirements.txt

I'm trying to fork a project repo and have pip install from my git address instead of theirs.

However, when I run:

```
pip install -e .
```

I see it still downloads from their hosted version:

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/...
```

Despite me specifying my repo address in the setup.py (i.e..)

```
install_requires=[
    'packagename @ https://github.com....'
    ...
]
```

How can I get around this so it just grabs what is at my repo instead?

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of pip, setuptools, and wheel?

Comment: @jwodder yes, everything is up to date

Comment: What does `pip --version` return?

Comment: @phd the URL-based dependency lookup is specified in PEP 508 and is supported by `pip>=18.1`, so it should be a valid specifier if `pip` is up to date.

Comment: I got it working, but I had to change the name so it didn't match the original package name, as well as specify the zip address of the package.